# configure an eclipse based IDE

Tags: eclipse, configuration, ide, business-process-management

I am new to programming. In fact this is my first job  and it has been just a month. I work for a company who use Savvion as BPM tool to automate some process. It has an Eclipse based IDE. The way it works is that  we can map business process using worksteps and linking those work steps.

My question is how to configure that eclipse based IDE so that it automatically puts some code when ever i tried to create a new workstep in the process. I am learning new things and I do not know where to start. I have gone through the folders where the IDE is installed and all I can find is jar files. could you please guide me as to where to start looking and any tips to get started.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use BPM studio (An Eclipse version savvion provided) where you can build process template as well as customize existing one.